# Is there an Open Data Cube (ODC) example/documentation on indexing data residing on Google Cloud

Tags: open-data-cube

Are there any Open Data Cube (ODC) examples/documentation that cover indexing data residing on Google Cloud.

I know there is documentation on indexing data on AWS S3 at https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ops/indexing.html#indexing-data-on-amazon-aws-s3

I am mainly exploring Google Cloud for Open Data Cube (ODC), not AWS.

Answer (score 4):

Google Cloud Storage support was only added to datacube-core recently and hasn't been officially released yet, so the documentation for this capability needs some work. In the mean time I'll add the examples here.

In the [DEA Proto repository](https://github.com/opendatacube/dea-proto/) there are some python scripts that allow you to index from google storage.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Google Storage support
gs-to-tar --bucket data.deadev.com --prefix mangrove_cover
dc-index-from-tar --env mangroves --ignore-lineage metadata.tar.gz
```

There are some dependency issues with installing datacube-core and DEA Proto, So I've put together the [datacube-index repository](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-index/) that wraps dea-proto in a docker image for easier use. This docker compose file shows how it can be used to index from a Google Storage bucket:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.3
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=opendatacube
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=opendatacubepassword
      - POSTGRES_USER=opendatacube
    restart: always

  index:
    image: opendatacube/index:google
    environment:
      - WMS_CONFIG_URL=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GeoscienceAustralia/dea-config/master/dev/services/wms/ows/wms_cfg.py
      - PRODUCT_URLS=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GeoscienceAustralia/dea-config/master/dev/products/mangrove/product-definition.yaml
      - DC_S3_INDEX_BUCKET=data.deadev.com
      - DC_S3_INDEX_PREFIX=mangrove_cover/-10_-18/
      - DC_S3_INDEX_SUFFIX=.yaml
      - DC_INDEX_PROTOCOL=gs
      - DC_RANGES_PRODUCT=mangrove_cover
      - DB_HOSTNAME=postgres
      - DB_USERNAME=opendatacube
      - DB_PASSWORD=opendatacubepassword
      - DB_DATABASE=opendatacube
      - DB_PORT=5432
    restart: on-failure
    command: 
      - /bin/bash
      - -c 
      - "cd index; ./create-index.sh"
```

When I put together some documentation on indexing from Google Cloud Storage I'll update this answer to reference it.

**N.B.** The docker image was built with the aim of indexing for [datacube-ows](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-ows/), so it'll also create some additional tables in your database and store the extents of your data there.